# why is the variable returning a different answer after an if statement

Tags: javascript, html

```js
function button() {
  var drop = document.getElementById("drop").value;
  console.log(drop);

  if (drop = "radio") {
    const para = document.createElement("button");
    para.innerHTML = "button";
    document.body.appendChild(para);
  } else if (drop = "button") {


  } else {

  }

};
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>hi</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Jayesh forms</h1>
  <select id="drop">
    <option>radio</option>
    <option>checkbox</option>
    <option>button</option>
  </select>
  <button id="button" onclick="button()">+</button>
  <p>1</p>
  <script src="js.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

I am making a replica of google forms where a checkbox will create a new element.
the drop variable is returning different answers what got wrong?

Answer (score 1):

In the `if` statement, I assume you want to compare it with a string but the code is assigning a new value to the `drop` variable instead. You can make use of `==` or `===` to do a comparison.

```js
if (drop === "radio") { 
  // rest of the code
}
```

It is also a good idea to make use of `const` (or `let`) instead of `var` so that you will probably get some IDE hints and it will be easier to debug.

Answer (score 0):

The issue with your **if** statement it should be **==** not **=**

```
function button() {
    var drop = document.getElementById("drop").value;
    console.log(drop);

    if (drop == "radio") {
        const para = document.createElement("button");
        para.innerHTML = "button";
        document.body.appendChild(para);
    } else if (drop == "button") {


    } else {

    }

};
```